# Dividing animated matplotlib plot line in different colors

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to get a better look on an animated graph using matplotlib but I have no idea on how to do that. For example, I have this animated graph as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)        # x-array
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    return line,

#Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,



ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=init,
    interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

What I want to do is to divide the graphic line in different colors by region. For example, I would like to have the curve from 0 < x < 2 red, from 2 < x < 4 green and from 4 < x < 6 blue. I have seen that the only possibility is to set a color for the whole line, but I have never seen this possibility of dividing line with different colors.
Thank so much for any help or hint on how to do that.

Comment: why not just use three lines?

Comment: Or `LineCollection` (there are a couple of good answers by JoeKington on SO showing how to do that)

Comment: It is also in the official examples: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html